# Unble to convert list of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Iam able to get the tuple and not able to convert into dictionary

```
for tag in list(tagged):
            w,p=tag
            print(w,p)
```

This is the output of tuple

```
    hi NN
    I PRP
    am VBP
    just RB
    testing VBG
```

It shows **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)** when I execute this code

```
dicts={w:p for w,p in tag}
        print(dicts)
```

Comment: try `in tagged`

Comment: I don't see why you can't just do `dicts = dict(tagged)`

Comment: Are we supposed to guess, what `tagged` is? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Its showing the same error when I did that

Comment: Then one of your list items isn't a tuple.

Comment: @ MrT  I showed the tuple output.tagged is the list of that tuple

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried it with the tagged instead of looping the tagged and it worked.

Comment: It would be just as easy, if not easier, to show us the value of `tagged` instead of the output of the first `for` loop.

Comment: @ chepner  **[('hi', 'NN'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('just', 'RB')**  This is the tagged.I got the output

Answer (score 0):

This is to show what should be the structure of `tagged` so that it works. I tried with your code and it works. Just one change in creating a dict.

```
tagged = [('hi', 'NN') , ('I', 'PRP'), ('am','VBP'), ('just','RB'), ('testing','VBG')]

#for tag in list(tagged):
#            w,p=tag
#            print(w,p)

dict(tagged)

{'I': 'PRP', 'am': 'VBP', 'hi': 'NN', 'just': 'RB', 'testing': 'VBG'}
```